# How to export a dynamic table into PDF in Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf, angular10

I want to make a PDF file using my existing dynamic table.I'm already tried the result will be 50% successful.I use [jsPDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf) the result be like[image].I want change column width and Header text too...

**Component.HTML**

```
id="htmlData" #htmlData
```

I use this in my container div

**Component.TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'
 @ViewChild('htmlData') htmlData: ElementRef;
    public openPDF():void {
    let DATA = this.htmlData.nativeElement;
    let doc = new jsPDF('l','pt', 'a4');
    doc.fromHTML(DATA.innerHTML,15,15,{
      'width':400,
      // autoSize:true,
    });
    doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
  }
```

Comment: create stackblitz of this.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ftgyqn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: library error coming in stackblitz

Comment: can we do in codesandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **jsPDF-AutoTable - Table plugin for jsPDF** npm

[jsPDF-AutoTable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf-autotable)